# Difference between SimpleJobBuilder and FlowJobBuilder in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

What is the difference between SimpleJobBuilder and FlowJobBuilder in Spring Batch? Why would I choose one over the other? Also, is there a difference in starting a step with start() rather than flow()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the difference between SimpleJobBuilder and FlowJobBuilder in Spring Batch?

A [SimpleJob](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/job/SimpleJob.html) runs steps sequentially while a [FlowJob](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/FlowJob.html) can run complex flows of steps (branching, parallelism, etc). Each type of job has its own builder.

> Why would I choose one over the other?

It depends on the type of job you want to build.

> Also, is there a difference in starting a step with start() rather than flow()?

`JobBuilder#start` returns a `SimpleJobBuilder` while `JobBuilder#flow` returns a `JobFlowBuilder`. So this is related to the previous point and it depends on the type of job you are trying to build.